# How can I receive inbound text trough Twilio on monday?

Tags: text, twilio, inbound

I'm trying to use Twilio for Automated messages through Monday. unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to receive the inbound responses from customers, Can someone guide me if you've figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can forward SMS messages from a Twilio number to your personal mobile number:

[Forwarding SMS messages to another phone number](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134287-Forwarding-SMS-messages-to-another-phone-number)

A more full featured blog to be able to send/receive is found here.

[SMS Forwarding and Responding Using Twilio and JavaScript](https://www.twilio.com/blog/sms-forwarding-and-responding-using-twilio-and-javascript)

You can also use Twilio Studio to drag/drop widgets on the Studio Canvas to easily do this.

[All Studio Tutorials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials)
-> https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/how-to-set-up-auto-responder